# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token :3000/__next

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

Getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when running next 14.0.3 locally.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token 

:3000/_next/static/c…s/app/layout.js:436
```

If i let it timeout it gives me a hydration error.
I've commented all my code out and just have the layout component

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk app/layout failed.
(timeout: http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/app/layout.js)
```

```
Call Stack
__webpack_require__.f.j
file:///C:/Users/atw0502d/source/repos/mysite/site/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (853:29)
<unknown>
file:///C:/Users/atw0502d/source/repos/mysite/site/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (155:40)
Array.reduce
<anonymous>
__webpack_require__.e
file:///C:/Users/atw0502d/source/repos/mysite/site/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (154:67)
fn.e
file:///C:/Users/atw0502d/source/repos/mysite/site/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (391:50)
loadChunk
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (202:31)
preloadModule
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (128:0)
resolveModule
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (1756:0)
processFullRow
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (1827:0)
processBinaryChunk
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (1975:0)
progress
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (2055:0)
```

Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>

```
import './globals.css';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import Header from './header/page';
import Footer from './footer/page';
import Link from 'next/link';
import styles from './Styles.module.css';
import { Suspense } from 'react';
import { Skeleton } from '@mui/material';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Site ',
  description: 'My Site',
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" id="page-container">
      <body className={`${inter.className} `}>
        <div className="w-screen bg-white">
          <Suspense fallback={<Skeleton width={1500} height={200}></Skeleton>}>
            <Link
              href="#main"
              className={styles.stmcl}
              style={{ width: '300px' }}
            >
              Skip To Content
            </Link>
          </Suspense>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="bg-white" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
            <Suspense
              fallback={<Skeleton width={1500} height={200}></Skeleton>}
            >
              <Header />
            </Suspense>
            <main id="content" className="min-h-[40em] w-full">
              <Suspense
                fallback={<Skeleton width={1500} height={200}></Skeleton>}
              >
                {children}
              </Suspense>
            </main>
          </div>
          <Suspense fallback={<Skeleton width={1500} height={200}></Skeleton>}>
            <Footer />
          </Suspense>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not easily possible to tell without readable code. Doesn't need to be the whole file; just the problem function with anything sensitive replaced by something "equivalent". Without that best guess is missing punctuation - quote, parentheses, bracket. A lint tool may help find it and prevent more in the future.

Comment: posted my layout.tsx, if you need more let me know. i tried commenting a lot of that out in various ways, still issue.